# Limit the width of a column

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

With the code below, the columns expands to the width of the widest element.
How can I limit the width to say, 20 characters?

```
    def populate_using_tkinter(frame, project_list):
        label_Name_column = Tkinter.Label(frame, text="Name",  anchor="w", borderwidth=1 relief="solid")
        label_Detail_column = Tkinter.Label(frame, text="Detail", borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
        label_Name_column.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=("W", "E"))
        label_Detail_column.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=("W", "E"))
```

Comment: 1st you should change your sticky to `sticky="ew"`There is no need to use a tuple here. As for preventing the column from expanding you want to disable propagation on the container.

Comment: Thanks for your !tuple suggestion.  How to disable propagation?

Comment: `container_name.grid_propagate(False)` should do the trick. That said it will affect everything in that container. So make sure you use a different frame for everything else.

Comment: You are correct; It does affect everything. I've added code to better illustrate the situation. I am displaying a grid (a table) and I have a frame passed in as a parameter. How do I use 2 frames? I would only want to limit the detail column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, the `grid` geometry manager doesn't let you set the maximum size of a column. It is designed to shrink or grow to exactly fit its contents.

One solution is to use frames for columns, then you can configure a frame to remain a specific width. The main downside to this solution is that you no longer have a grid *per se* -- you have a series of columns. If the items in the columns have different heights, it is very difficult to get your rows to line up.

A simpler solution is to make sure that the preferred width of all of the widgets is smaller than the desired column size. You can then set the size for the column and have the widgets expand to fill. When you do this, they will only expand to the size of the column, and not to their maximum size.

Here is a simple example with two columns, where the second column is constrained to be 100 pixels. It does this by setting the `minsize` of the column and a `weight` of zero, and then creating a label widget that is smaller than the `minsize`. By having the widget stick to the sides of the column, it will grow to be 100 pixels wide.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x100")

# We want to constrain the column to 100 pixels, so we
# set a minsize and a weight of zero so that it will
# not grow any larger. 
root.columnconfigure(1, minsize=100, weight=0)

# Add two labels. For the label in the second column we will
# force its size to be as small as possible. Later, we will
# configure it to grow to fill its column
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="This is a wide label", background="pink")
label2 = tk.Label(root, anchor="w", width=1, text="This is also a wide label", background="bisque")

# Add the labels, and configure them to fill their columns
label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
label2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with grid_propagate that should show well enough how it affects the container. Here we use 2 frames and 2 buttons. The buttons make it easier to show how each widget and container is expanding and also to show how you can lock in the size of a frame.

Keep in mind each frame is set up in pixels for width and height. Widgets are set up as character length and height so it is affected by font formatting but we dont need to show that in this example.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        left_frame = tk.Frame(self, width=200, height=200)
        left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        left_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        left_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        left_frame.grid_propagate(False)

        right_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
        right_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        right_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        tk.Button(left_frame, text='test left frame').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Button(right_frame, text='test right frame').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')


App().mainloop()
```